# C# How to declare lambda or anonymous function type in method argument list?

Tags: c#

I don't know if this is possible in C#. But here's what I'm trying to do:
An interface that declares a method with a completion block / callback / lambda / whatever you want to call it. Seems simple enough. But, here's a first attempt:

```
namespace N {
  interface MyInterface {
    delegate void CompletionBlock();
    void doSomething(CompletionBlock completionBlock);
  }
}
```

But interfaces can't declare delegates. Ok, how about this?

```
namespace N {
  public delegate void CompletionBlock();
  interface MyInterface {
    void doSomething(CompletionBlock completionBlock);
  }
}
```

Sure that works, but now, say I declare another type of CompletionBlock, one which takes an argument for instance. I can't call the type CompletionBlock because it'll clash with the above type, if inside the same namespace.

Then there's Action and Func. But even Action takes a parameter, and I want no parameters. So Action doesn't seem like a viable candidate. Really, all I want, is a way of inlining the concept of "anonymous block as long as the signature is void(void). Something like this:

```
namespace N {
  interface MyInterface {
    void doSomething(typeof(()=>) completionBlock);
  }
}
```

But lambdas don't really have a type in C#. Do they at least have signatures? 
Basically, is there any way around this?

In Objective-C, for instance, blocks are of type NSBlock, even though their signatures themselves are not easily accessible, but one can create a method that takes a block with a specific signature. For instance:

```
- (void)doSomething:(void(^)(void))completionBlock
```

Would be a method that takes a block with no parameters and no return type, and you'd call the method like so, for instance:

```
[obj doSomething:^(){your block code}];
```

Comment: There _is_ a [parameterless `Action()` delegate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.action%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). Is that ok for your usage?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Then there's Action and Func. But even Action takes a parameter, and I want no parameters. So Action doesn't seem like a viable candidate.

If you use `Action` (not `Action<T>`), it does not take parameters.

```
namespace N {
  interface MyInterface {
    void doSomething(Action completionBlock);
  }  
}
```

This allows you to write:

```
yourInstance.doSomething(() => DoWhatever(foo));
```

Or, if `DoWhatever` is `void DoWhatever()`, just:

```
yourInstance.doSomething(DoWhatever);
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [`Action<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.action%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) or [`Func<TResult>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534960%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) or one of their siblings or just [`Action`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.action%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) in your case.

`Action<...>` don't return anything where as `Func<..., TResult>` do.